# Any studies on how much crime was done during pandemic? How it affected society after

Tags: crime, disease

I would like to know during pandemics if any studies were done about crime before and after said pandemic? Did it go up did it go down? How did they deal with those they caught and did they put into effect anything that might help in the future? How did it affect a society after the pandemic?

Comment: I did a really quick search, and the only thing I came up with was an online news magazine article saying that the 1918 flu pandemic reduced global crime, but with no reference for that assertion. https://couriernewsroom.com/2020/05/27/what-u-s-crime-rates-went-up-and-down-during-the-coronavirus-shutdowns/

Comment: The answer will vary significantly by country and time.  Are you asking about this pandemic, about the Spanish Flu, or the Great Plague of 1666?  "Crime" is defined differently in different countries.

Comment: potentially useful [Cybercrime increase during pandemic](https://www.maketecheasier.com/europol-warns-cybercrime-increase-coronavirus-pandemic/?utm_source=social&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=rssfeed) - current events vice history, but might help with someone else's research or context

Comment: Can you clarify the phrase "before and after said pandemic?" That makes it seem like you're referring to a specific pandemic. Are you interested in a specific pandemic or in any pandemic?  The question is intriguing; I just don't understand the intent well enough to begin research.